# How to choose good journal in neuroscience with no fee?

Tags: publications, fees, neuroscience

I'm a post-doc but with some other post-doc from other labs we are doing research in neurosciences in our free time, and so we are not funding for these projects.
But we would like to publish in a recognized "serious" journal (but no need for a high impact factor).
We tried to look at https://doaj.org/ but we do not know on which criterion to sort the thousands of journals listed or decide if it is a serious journal or not.

On which criteria can we consider a journal being "serious"?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not at all familiar with the landscape of journals in neurosciences, so I cannot give you a concrete journal name. But consider this: you are writing a paper to be submitted to a neurosciences journal. I presume that this paper includes references to related work, also published in similar journals. Which journals appear most often in your bibliography? Consider those for your publication first.

Alternatively, seek out the publication records of neurosciences researchers that you truly admire, and find out which journals appear frequently on their (recent) publication records. If top neurosciences researchers publish frequently in a journal, it is likely to be a recognized journal accepting neurosciences papers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in our specific case all the journals we usually cite or publish have fees (authors have to pay at least 800$), and as we are working on a side project with no funding at all, we can't pay for such journals...

Comment: @Dadep Most neuroscience journals require payment. The only ones I have found that do not are either not neuroscience-specific (and typically have a very high bar for submissions) or have a medical focus and aren't really neuroscience journals per se. For many, $800 is really quite a tiny fee compared to all the other costs of doing research, but if that isn't true for your country you might see if a journal offers discounts (J Neuroscience does, for example).

Comment: so disclosing research can only be done by rich people... I think we will just use bioArXiv and try to have a review thanks to "Peer Community In ".
Thanks!

Comment: @Dadep To the contrary, to some extent paying journals for publishing is often part of making them more available to the (poor) public. $800 is a fraction of a salary of a single researcher in much of the world. The electrodes my lab puts on a single mouse mean that the cost of a single experiment in a single animal exceeds $800, not even counting one-time expenses for recording equipment and software in the $10ks.